# Windows XP Login Box Customization

Tags: windows, user-interface, authentication, windows-xp, winlogon

A slightly weird question, and not one relating to programming, but a rather GUI based question.

I would like to change the Windows XP Ribbon Image, that appears at the Classic Logon Screen for Windows XP.
See the attatched images for more info.

This is completely possible, I have seen it done before, it will be somewhere In the registry.

Thanks,
Dan
[image: Current]
[image: Required]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the bitmaps are actually contained within a dll, but the part you are concerned with is not one bitmap image. The whole box is composed of a bitmap image on top, a little bitmap to the left, and text strings all contained in this dll.

c:\windows\system32\msgina.dll
I followed this document, and downloaded "Resource Hacker" (linked on the page) to edit the dll.

http://www.infocellar.com/winxp/customize-logon-screen.htm

To anyone trying this: BACKUP MSGINA.DLL BEFORE YOU DO ANYTHING.

The exact bitmap depends on the version, and frankly, I am not which one it is. Note that the bitmap only covers the top half of the login box. The rest is still contained within the msgina.dll, and can also edited using Resource Hacker. If you are using XP Pro, the image you probably want is in Bitmap>101 or 107.

You can use use Resource Hacker to copy out the bitmap, and to bring it back in.

The string text is contained in String Table>114.

Comment: Hey Aladdin! This looks correct, except for the fact that this is for the standard logon screen (the one where you can click the username as opposed to typing it). Do you think this will still work for the classic logon screen (the windowed one).

Comment: the link is for the login screen but the file I pointed to contains all the images in windows xp dialogs just download Resource Hacker and you will find the exact image on the numbers I have pointed out.

Comment: Awesome Stuff! Thank's Aladdin!!

Comment: Hmmm. I tried replacing both resource 103 and 107, the corresponding images, but it doesn't seem to be working. Each time the machine restarts a fresh copy of msgina.dll seems to spawn.

Comment: I am not on a windows machine right now but I think you have to modify some setting on the registry to allow modifying the file check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378750(v=vs.85).aspx and I am sure you can find alot of information if you searched for "modifying msgina"

Comment: Hello all, I've solved this. Simply editing MSGINA.DLL on it's own is not effective. Windows seems to create a 'fresh' copy of msgina.dll each time it restarts, which is weird. You need to rename your edited dll (something like msginaedited.dll), and head over to the registry: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon], and create a new REG_SZ (String Value), named GinaDLL Specify the data inside the string to the renamed dll (msginaedited.dll). Adding the complete filepath may also help if you are running into issues, rather than just using msginaedited.dll)